# edge sliding using python script

Tags: python, scripting, edges

I want to use edge slide operation using python. But I got error "*RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.transform.edge_slide.poll() expected a view3d region & editmesh*".

I searched and found several solutions for loop cuts but didn't find specifically for edge loops. I modified the loop cut script for edge loop but didn't work. can anyone help?

links are:
[Loop Cut and Slide using Python not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160739/loop-cut-and-slide-using-python-not-working)

[How to use loopcut_slide operation without any UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196367/how-to-use-loopcut-slide-operation-without-any-ui)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your concern. I found the solution by doing some research by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer which solved my problem. I need to find out area in view 3d and other related info pack those things into override variable and put that variable at the first input of edge_slide function.

```
import bpy
def view3d_find( return_area = False ):

    for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            v3d = area.spaces[0]
            
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    if return_area: return region, v3d, area
region, v3d, area = view3d_find(True)
#we need to put those values into a single variable in the following
override = {
    'scene': bpy.context.scene,'region' : region,'area': area,'space': v3d}
#must be in edit mode
bpy.ops.transform.edge_slide(override,value=0.3,  mirror=True, correct_uv=True)
```